# "NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed" on Google contact delete

Tags: javascript, api, google-contacts-api, http-status-code-405

I am trying to delete a Google Contact through javascript. As per v3 of Google Contacts api I have defined:

```
scope to https://www.google.com/m8/feeds
```

And authenticated user, and got the access_token.
And as per the v3 documentation on [this page](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/), trying to delete a contact like this:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/temp123info@gmail.com?access_token=ya29.AHES6ZQoqUgoYmDzXyo-WsSlKv1-_2D_HzmXuH-wBuTR3e1ADxO0VWM',
type: 'DELETE',
success: function(res)
{
    console.log(res);
},

error: function(error)
{
    console.log(error);
}
});
```

Getting this error:

```
   "NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed - https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/laiquedaudpota43@gmail.com/full/temp123info@gmail.com?access_token=ya29.AHES6ZQoqUgoYmDzXyo-WsSlKv1-_2D_HzmXuH-wBuTR3e1ADxO0VWM"
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19762065/how-can-i-manage-google-accounts-contacts-through-javascript/19766959#19766959) .

Make use of the google client api for javascript.

Answer (score 5):

You are experiencing something called [CORSS (Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest)](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html)

if you open chrome dev tools you will see that the browser ignored your 'delete' type and sent OPTIONS instead.

this is happening when you try to call a server from other origin, the browser will fire an extra request with data type OPTIONS to the server to know what is required in order to send your original delete post.
The problem is that the server is not allowing 'OPTIONS' method type.
if you ask me, ill try to find proxy (jsonp) service for google contact . or an api

Please have a look here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js

I think you should use their standard api for that.

Comment: How about using jsonp?

Comment: @sufyan.shoaib - the server needs to support that, he will have to read the api documentation. since he is not using a standard api. it is impossible. i updated my answer and added a link to the api

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing, by a call to delete contacts but trying to follow v3 of google contacts. The above URL you have provided is for v1 which is obsolete, even v2 is obsolete, and many(almost everything) doesnt work now on older versions. v3 of the google contacts doesnt provide a good javascript client library to access v3 api calls, unfortunately

Comment: Ok, this can help you: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js

Comment: I have also looked into the client library, actually it doesnt support  google contacts service : // Step 4: Load the Google+ API
        gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function() {})..... its [api explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/) doesnt support this service..

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i am looking into this, will get back asap