# Adding a contact using Google Contact API in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-contacts-api

I am playing with Google API in JavaScript. I managed to get a list of my contact with the following code :

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?access_token=' + access_token + '&alt=json',
    method: 'GET',

    error: function(error) {
        alert('An error has occured during contact creation.');
    },

    success: function(data, status){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

I tried to add a contact by changing GET to POST and adding my contact data in the request body. But as soon as I add a data attribute, or change GET to POST, the server answers me the really annoying "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error.

Any idea?

I am following this documentation : https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/?csw=1#creating_contacts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do this from the browser, although not obvious *at all*.

Based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19766959/1135942), we learn that there is method called [`gapi.client.request`](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/javascript#gapiclientrequestargs) that can be used for this (instead of jQuery's `$.ajax`).

Accordingly, **for editing** we can do:

```
gapi.client.request({
    method : 'PUT', 
    path:'m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/<contactId>/<editRevisionFromGET>', 
    body : {"version":"1.0","encoding":"UTF-8","entry": ...}, 
    callback : function(data) { 
        console.log(data); 
    }
});
```

The important parts for editing in here are:

1. send back the entire entry you got before from a read
2. use the current ID given at the end of the URL in the `entry.link` element with relation type `edit` (or you'll get a HTTP Status 409 - Conflict)

Side note: 
Notice that these requests actually are done to `https://content.googleapis.com/` ...
From some quick tests, it seems you can do ?all? requests just to that URL instead of google.com, and then CORS issues disappear.

Comment: What is the format of `"entry":` to update contacts?? I am sending it like this: `{"entry":{"phone":{"cell": req.body.mobile}}}` but its giving error in response status 415 `invalid input`

Answer (score 0):

```
gapi.client.request({
    method : 'PUT', 
    path:'m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/<contactId>/<editRevisionFromGET>', 
    body : {"version":"1.0","encoding":"UTF-8","entry": ...}, 
    callback : function(data) { 
        console.log(data); 
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).