# Unable to resolve Network Error: 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: knockout.js, odata, http-verbs

I have an application in which I am using OData and Knockout Js. In my application I am using POST, GET and DELETE HTTP Verb and when I hosted my application, the GET and POST doesn't throw any error but DELETE does throw an error, not sure how to fix it.

Following is where I am using DELETE

```
self.remove = function (canadiancrude) {

        var conf = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?");
        if (conf == true) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/odata/Canadiancrudes(' + canadiancrude.Id + ')',
                type: 'DELETE',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json'
            });
        }
    }
```

And the error is

```
405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.

"NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed
```

How do I fix it

Comment: does this method have the [Authorize] attribute?

Comment: Yes, the controller method has [Authorize] attribute to the entire page not only for this DELETE and they are working fine

Comment: Might be a CORS issue... does this SO article help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19675835/networkerror-405-method-not-allowed-on-google-contact-delete

Comment: Also use Fiddler to verify that DELETE was actually the verb sent by the browser.  It might also give you more information in the response than reported by the browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even Adding the below lines to my web.config helped me

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
    </modules>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to modify your request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/odata/Canadiancrudes(' + canadiancrude.Id + ')',
    type: 'DELETE',
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: { 
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-HTTP-Method-Override": "DELETE" }
});
```

Also, if you use IIS you could do next steps:
1) In Control Panel, click Programs and Features, and then click Turn Windows Features on or off.
2) Expand Internet Information Services, then World Wide Web Services, then Common HTTP Features.
3) **Unselect** WebDAV Publishing, and then click OK.